# MySQL Workbench Table Data Import Wizard failure (json file)

Tags: json, utf-8, boolean, mysql-workbench, hebrew

I am trying to import data from a json file into a MySQL Workbench table. Here is a snippet of my JSON file to understand how the data is structured:

```
[
  { "English": "Acne", "Hebrew": "חצ'קונים", "isFamily": true, "id": 1 },
  { "English": "Acre", "Hebrew": "דונם", "isFamily": false, "id": 2 },
  { "English": "Addendum", "Hebrew": "תוֹסֶפֶת", "isFamily": false, "id": 3 },
  { "English": "Advertise", "Hebrew": "לְפַרְסֵם", "isFamily": true, "id": 4 }
]
```

I tried using "Table Data Import Wizard" and to select the JSON file. it seemed to have succeeded, before executing the import it showed this demonstration of how the data will be implemented in the table:

[image: Table Data Import Wizard]

How ever, when finalizing the import, no rows were added.

I've tried changing the tables Charset/Collation to utf-8 and utf8 and utf8_unicode_ci but it goes back to default after I apply the changes. I've also tried changing isFamily column Datatype to BOOLEAN instead of TINYINT(1), but it also goes back to TINYINT(1) after I apply the changes.

Does it have to do with the fact the table has some columns in Hebrew and some in English?
is it because of the Boolean issue? How can I solve this?

Would appreciate any help!